# How to append to a file (in the same dict after restarting the server), using python socket programming

Tags: python, dictionary, sockets

Here's the code I wrote for a server, which requests user info and stores them into a file:

```
# Function : For each client 
def threaded_client(connection):
    ''' codes that request and receive user massage... '''
    # write the info into credentials.txt:
    with open('credentials.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(credentials, file = f)
```

Ideally, when I exit the server and restart it, all the old and new info should be kept in the same dict.

Expected output:

```
{'username_1': 'his password', 'username_2': 'her password', 'a': 'b'}
```

Actual output:

```
{'username_1': 'his password'}
{'username_2': 'her password', 'a': 'b'}
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: As an aside, writing the `str()` of a Python object to a file is not a great idea.  Suggest using JSON instead.  Read the existing `credentials.json` if it exists with `json.load`, modify the data, then write `credientials.json` (not append) with the updated information with `json.dump`.  Also, what does socket programming have to do with updating a file?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Actually, it's homework, and the spec told us to keep a TXT file of the user Infos (so it's like a simple database for the server), so no JSON :(  @MarkTolonen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're setting your `open` mode to `a` (append), when writing to the file, the string you write to will be appended to the end of the file. So in your case, you're printing `{'username_1': 'his password'}` in the first thread and then `{'username_2': 'her password', 'a': 'b'}` on the second thread to 'credentials.txt' file as 2 separate lines. You should update your `threaded_client` function to read and parse the content of `credentials.txt` and immediately update it with new credentials data and then overwrite `credentials.txt` file with the new data. Just make sure that only one thread can have read and write access to `credentials.txt` file at any point in time when the server is running

```
# Function : For each client
def threaded_client(connection):
    ''' codes that request and receive user massage... '''
    # read the info from credentials.txt:
    with open('credentials.txt', 'r') as f:
        try:
            current_credentials = eval(f.readline())
        except:
            current_credentials = {} # in case of empty file
    # overwrite credentials.txt with new credentials info:
    with open('credentials.txt', 'w') as f:
        current_credentials.update(credentials)
        print(current_credentials, file = f)
```